# Fogbugz query to show all of my closed tickets?

Tags: fogbugz

I'm new to fogbugz, so I may be making some incorrect assumptions. However, my understanding is that when a ticket is Closed, then the assigned To field becomes "Closed".

How can I search for all of the tickets for which I was the assigned person BEFORE it was closed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to do this via UI / Dashboard, instead you have to use FOGBUGZ API & code to get the data you want.  Use the API to get the tickets under milestone and then loop through to get the Assigned To / Developer . That's how we have been playing.

[FogBugz XML API Development](https://developers.fogbugz.com/?W194)

[FogBugz XML API version 8](http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api?se_found=1)

Comment: I've never used the fogbugz API. do you have a sample or something you could point me at?

Comment: Hey @BrianPostow - looks like i missed your comment - its late but i will register here - hope this helps

https://developers.fogbugz.com/?W194 and http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api?se_found=1 

fogbugz api is easy to use and described well in above links .

if you want use code to parse fogbugz response xml - try referring to this tool / app - it helped me great in using apis http://fogbugzworkingon.codeplex.com/